# List child element is not able to find by using the Appium tool

Tags: xamarin.forms, automated-tests, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, appium-ios

I have worked in the Appium testing tool (Version: 1.15.1), I am testing to Xamarin hybrid app (iOS and Android). I can select the view and also get xpath. But, In the list view, I am not able to select the child elements in the list view and also couldn’t find the xpath for child elements.

[image]

We have given automation id in source code. Even Appium inspector is not able to get elements. We used Xamarin.Form 4.3, 4.2, 3.5, and 3.0 versions.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell AutomationId="MyViewCell" AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="True" >
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="True" >
                                <Label x:Name="titleLbl" AutomationId="TitleLabel" Text="{Binding Text}" d:Text="{Binding .}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="16" AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="True" />
                                <Label x:Name="desc" AutomationId="DescLabel" Text="{Binding Description}" d:Text="Item descripton" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" FontSize="13" AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="True" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Kindly give solutions for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: One way is to print out the page source and see if you can get the individual xml. But the issue may also lie with if Xamarin 's UI component  follow XCUIElement.

Comment: we can get the IDs from other components. but in the list view, we can't get the elements. if it has a problem means, would you suggest any other way for a hybrid app?

Comment: This issue is more likely on Xamarin if it does not include ID (or other locators) for the child elements. Appium inspector will not be able to retrieve this  if there is no information.

One way to find out is the get the source of the xml page that you are looking. If there is no path for the child elements , it will not work with Appium Inspector. You will need to ask the dev to add it.